# str_extract to extract number between _

Tags: r, string

I have the following vector and I want to extract the number between the c and the last "_", so far my code does not work.

```
stringr::str_extract(c("revenue_d_p2_c16_s4", "revenue_d_p2_c9_s4", "revenue_d_p2_c99_s4"), "(?<=c)\\d(?=\\_)")
```

The results must be: 16, 9 and 99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that you don't have a `+` after the `\\d`, so you are not capturing the numbers with more than a single digit

```r
str <- c("revenue_d_p2_c16_s4", "revenue_d_p2_c9_s4", "revenue_d_p2_c99_s4")

stringr::str_extract(str, "(?<=c)\\d+(?=_)")
#> [1] "16" "9"  "99"
```

Or use `sub` from base R instead

```r
sub("^.*\\c(\\d+)_.*$", '\\1', str)
#> [1] "16" "9"  "99"
```